# Precio Real del inventario dependiendo de cantidad y ultimas entradas (PROMEDIO PONDERADO)

Tags: postgresql, sql

**Hola, mi pregunta es compleja y creo que algo complicada.**

Resulta que tengo un inventario el cual va variando según las ventas e ingresos, quiero saber el costo real de mi inventario pero no me da exacto ya que los precios de entrada varían en cada ingreso, lo que quiero es que se calcule el inventario actual (ya lo tengo hecho) pero que basado en ese inventario me consulte los precios de costo y realice un promedio ponderado teniendo en cuenta la cantidad de cada ingreso sin superar el inventario.

Este es el Script de mi base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE configuraciones (
  id serial  primary key,
  nombre_negocio varchar(60),
  nit_negocio varchar(15),
  contacto_negocio varchar(15),
  contacto2_negocio varchar(15),
  direccion varchar,
  ruta_backup varchar,
  nombre_impresora varchar, -- la de hoja 17*12
  tipo_impresora varchar, -- termica/ 17*12 / carta / etc
  imprimir_factura integer,
  productos_repetidos integer, -- nuevo
  utilidad_venta integer,
  utilidad_mayorista integer,
  utilidad_credito integer,
  iva integer
);
--alter table configuraciones add column imprimir_factura varchar


CREATE TABLE perfiles (
  id serial  primary key,
  perfil varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial  primary key,
  nombre varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  password varchar NOT NULL,
  user_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  direccion varchar(80),
  telefono varchar(50),
  telefono2 varchar(50),
  sitioweb varchar(50),
  estado varchar(8),
  email varchar(50),
  id_perfil int NOT NULL,
  constraint fk_perfil foreign key (id_perfil) references perfiles (id)
);

CREATE TABLE cajas(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  total double precision,
  retiro double precision,
  saldo double precision,
  fecha_cierre date,
  hora_cierre varchar(8),
  CONSTRAINT claveprimariacaja PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE contactos
(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código del contacto
  nombre varchar(60) NOT NULL, -- Nombre del contacto
  cedula varchar(15) NOT NULL unique, -- Número de C.I. del contacto
  direccion varchar(80), -- Dirección del contacto
  ciudad varchar(80), -- Dirección del contacto
  contacto varchar(50), -- Nº de teléfono del contacto
  contacto2 varchar(50), -- Nº de celular del contacto
  descuento double precision,
  email varchar(50), -- Email del contacto
  forma_pago varchar(20), 
  cuenta varchar(20),
  tipo_cuenta varchar(20),
  numero_cuenta varchar(20),
  observaciones varchar,
  proveedor integer,
  CONSTRAINT claveprimaria_ PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE retiros(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  fecha date,
  hora varchar(8),
  monto double precision,
  detalle varchar(400),
  id_user integer,
  CONSTRAINT claveprimariaretiros PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id_user_r FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users (id)
);

CREATE TABLE sucursales(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código del sucursal
  nombre varchar(20), -- Nombre o razón social de sucursal
  telefono varchar(20), -- Contacto
  responsable varchar(20), -- Nombre del responsable en la sucursal
  direccion varchar(30), -- Dirección de la sucursal
  CONSTRAINT sucursales_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);

CREATE TABLE familias( 
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(50), 
  CONSTRAINT pkfamilias PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);

CREATE TABLE marcas(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(50), 
  CONSTRAINT pkmarcas PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE facturas_cabeceras(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código de la factura cabecera
  codigo varchar(20),
  id_contacto integer, -- Código del contacto en la factura cabecera
  id_user integer, -- Código del contacto en la factura cabecera
  total double precision, -- Monto total a pagar
  fecha date, -- Fecha de emisión de la factura
  estado char(1), -- Estado de la factura
  hora varchar(8), -- Hora de emisión de la factura
  tiva1 double precision,
  porcentaje_descuento double precision, -- Monto entregado
  monto_descuento double precision, -- Monto entregado
  tipo_factura varchar(10),
  CONSTRAINT pkfacturacabecera PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkcontactoc FOREIGN KEY (id_contacto) REFERENCES contactos (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id_userc FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users (id)
);

CREATE TABLE productos(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código del producto
  id_marca integer NOT NULL,
  id_familia integer NOT NULL,
  codigo_barras varchar unique,
  descripcion varchar(500), -- Descripcion del producto
  precio_costo double precision, -- Precio costo del producto
  precio_venta double precision, -- Precio mayorista del producto
  precio_mayorista double precision, -- Precio mayorista del producto
  precio_credito double precision, -- Precio crédito del producto
  cant_paquete integer, -- Cantidad por paquete del producto
  iva integer, -- Cantidad por paquete del producto
  id_user integer,
  id_proveedor integer,
  CONSTRAINT clave_primaria PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_familia FOREIGN KEY (id_familia) REFERENCES familias (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_cre_pro FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_proveedor FOREIGN KEY (id_proveedor) REFERENCES contactos (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_marca FOREIGN KEY (id_marca) REFERENCES marcas (id)
  );

CREATE TABLE tipo_ingreso(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código de la factura cabecera
  nombre varchar(100), -- Código del contacto en la factura cabecera
  CONSTRAINT pk_tipo_ingresos PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE ingresos_mercancias_cabecera(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código de la factura cabecera
  no_factura varchar(100),
  id_proveedor integer, -- proveedor del ingreso
  id_user integer, -- usuario que creo el ingreso
  id_tipo integer, -- tipo de ingreso
  total double precision, 
  fecha date, -- Fecha de emisión de la factura
  hora varchar(8),
  CONSTRAINT pk_ingresos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_proveedor FOREIGN KEY (id_proveedor) REFERENCES contactos (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_tipo_ingreso FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo) REFERENCES tipo_ingreso (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id_useri FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users (id)
);
CREATE TABLE ingresos_mercancias_detalle(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código de la factura cabecera
  id_producto integer, -- Código del contacto en la factura cabecera
  id_ingreso_cabecera integer, -- Código del contacto en la factura cabecera
  cantidad double precision, -- Monto total a pagar
  precio_iva double precision, 
  precio_entrada double precision, 
  CONSTRAINT pk_ingresos_detalle PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_cabecera FOREIGN KEY (id_ingreso_cabecera) REFERENCES ingresos_mercancias_cabecera(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_producto FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id)
);

CREATE TABLE facturas_detalles(
  id serial, -- Código del detalle de la factura
  id_cabecera integer,
  id_producto integer, -- Código del producto en el detalle de la factura
  cantidad double precision, -- Cantidad vendida del producto
  valor_unitario double precision, -- Precio unitario del producto
  descuento double precision, -- Subtotal
  iva double precision,
  subtotal double precision, -- Subtotal
  CONSTRAINT pkfacturadetalle PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkcabecera FOREIGN KEY (id_cabecera) REFERENCES facturas_cabeceras (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkproducto FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id)
);

CREATE TABLE creditos_apartados(
  id serial,
  id_factura integer,
  id_user integer,
  abono double precision,
  fecha_plazo_final date,
  CONSTRAINT pkcreditos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_cre_apar FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES   users (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id_factura FOREIGN KEY (id_factura) REFERENCES facturas_cabeceras (id)
);

CREATE TABLE devoluciones(
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Código de la factura cabecera
  id_factura integer, -- Código del contacto en la factura cabecera
  id_user integer, -- Código del contacto en la factura cabecera
  total double precision, -- Monto total a pagar
  fecha date, -- Fecha de emisión de la factura
  hora varchar(8), -- Fecha de emisión de la factura
  CONSTRAINT pkdevoluciones PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkfactura FOREIGN KEY (id_factura) REFERENCES facturas_cabeceras (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id_userdev FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users (id)
);

CREATE TABLE devoluciones_detalles(
  id serial, -- Código del detalle de la factura
  id_cabecera_devolucion integer,
  id_producto integer, -- Código del producto en el detalle de la factura
  cantidad double precision, -- Cantidad vendida del producto
  valor_unitario double precision, -- Precio unitario del producto
  total double precision, 
  CONSTRAINT pkdetallesdev PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_cabecera_devoluciones FOREIGN KEY (id_cabecera_devolucion) REFERENCES devoluciones (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkproducto_devolucion FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id)
);

CREATE TABLE cuentas(
  id serial, 
  nombre varchar(50), 
  CONSTRAINT pk_cuentas PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE cuentas_prestamos( -- se creo la tabla cuentas_prestamos para ser asosciada a los prestamos
  id serial, 
  nombre varchar(50), 
  CONSTRAINT pk_cuentas_prestamos PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE egresos(
  id serial, 
  id_user integer,
  id_contacto integer, 
  id_cuenta integer not NULL, 
  descripcion varchar,
  total double precision, 
  fecha date, -- Fecha de emisión del gasto
  hora varchar(8), -- hora de emisión del gasto
  caja integer, -- hora de emisión del gasto
  CONSTRAINT pk_otros_egresos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_cuenta_egresos FOREIGN KEY (id_cuenta) REFERENCES   cuentas (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_oegre FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES   users (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_contacto_oegre FOREIGN KEY (id_contacto) REFERENCES contactos (id)
);

CREATE TABLE otros_ingresos(
  id serial, 
  id_user integer,
  id_contacto integer, 
  descripcion varchar,
  total double precision, 
  fecha date, -- Fecha de emisión del gasto
  hora varchar(8), -- hora de emisión del gasto
  CONSTRAINT pk_otros_ingresos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_oingre FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES   users (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_contacto_oingre FOREIGN KEY (id_contacto) REFERENCES contactos (id)
);


CREATE TABLE cambios_eliminar(
  id serial,
  id_user integer,
  id_producto integer,
  descripcion varchar,
  cantidad double precision,
  camb_elim varchar(8),
  fecha date, 
  hora varchar(8), 
  CONSTRAINT pk_cambios_eliminar PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_camb FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES   users (id),
  CONSTRAINT fkproducto_cam_eli FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id)
);

CREATE TABLE abonos(
  id serial,
  id_creditos_apartados integer,
  id_user integer,
  abono double precision,
  fecha date,
  CONSTRAINT pk_abonos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_cre_apar FOREIGN KEY (id_creditos_apartados) REFERENCES   creditos_apartados (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_abonos FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES   users (id)
);

CREATE TABLE prestamos(
  id serial, 
  id_user integer,
  id_contacto integer, 
  id_cuenta integer, 
  descripcion varchar,
  total double precision, 
  fecha date, 
  hora varchar(8), 
  caja integer, 
  CONSTRAINT pk_prestamos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_prestamos FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES   users (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_cuenta_prestamos FOREIGN KEY (id_cuenta) REFERENCES  cuentas_prestamos (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_contacto_prestamos FOREIGN KEY (id_contacto) REFERENCES contactos (id)
);


CREATE TABLE abonos_prestamos(
  id serial,
  id_prestamo integer,
  id_user integer,
  abono double precision,
  fecha date,
  hora varchar(8), 
  CONSTRAINT pk_abono_prestamos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_prestamos FOREIGN KEY (id_prestamo) REFERENCES   prestamos (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_abono_prestamos FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES   users (id)
);



-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Inserts
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

insert into perfiles (id,perfil) values (1,'admin');
insert into perfiles (id,perfil) values (2,'cajero');
insert into users (id,nombre,password,user_name,id_perfil) values (1,'admin','6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b','admin',1);
insert into users (id,nombre,password,user_name,id_perfil) values (2,'caja','000c285457fc971f862a79b786476c78812c8897063c6fa9c045f579a3b2d63f','caja',2);
insert into contactos (id,nombre,cedula,direccion) values (1,'Ventas Diarias','0000','Home');
insert into configuraciones (id,nombre_negocio,ruta_backup,imprimir_factura,productos_repetidos) values (1,'contamonkey','vacio',0,0);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Funciones
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ingreso_abono_desde_cre_apar() --probar
returns trigger as $$
begin
  if (select count(id) from abonos where id_creditos_apartados=new.id)>0 then 
      insert into abonos (id,id_creditos_apartados,id_user,abono,fecha) values ((select max(id)+1 from abonos),new.id,new.id_user,new.abono,CURRENT_DATE);
      return null;
    else
      insert into abonos (id,id_creditos_apartados,id_user,abono,fecha) values ((select COALESCE(max(id),0)+1 from abonos),new.id,new.id_user,0,CURRENT_DATE);
      update abonos set abono=new.abono where id=(select max(id) from abonos);
      return null;
  end if;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ingreso_crap_desde_abono() 
returns trigger as $$
begin
  update creditos_apartados set abono=abono+new.abono where id=new.id_creditos_apartados;
return null;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION suma_saldo_crap_desde_Eliminar_abonos() -- este proceso suma stock a productos cuando se elimina un cambio_eliminar
returns trigger as $$
begin
  update creditos_apartados set abono=abono-old.abono where id=old.id_creditos_apartados;
  return null;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crea_abono_vacio_desde_prestamos() -- este proceso suma stock a productos cuando se elimina un cambio_eliminar
returns trigger as $$
begin
  insert into abonos_prestamos (id,id_prestamo,id_user,abono,fecha) 
    values ((select COALESCE(max(id),0)+1 from abonos_prestamos),new.id,new.id_user,0,CURRENT_DATE);
  return null;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--TRIGGERS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


create trigger insertar_abono_desde_cred_apart -- trigger relacionado a credito_apartados se encarga de ejecutar insert a abonos
after insert on creditos_apartados
for each row
execute procedure ingreso_abono_desde_cre_apar();

create trigger insertar_abono_crap_desde_abono -- trigger relacionado a abonos se encarga de ejecutar update a creditos_apartados
after insert on abonos
for each row
execute procedure ingreso_crap_desde_abono();

create trigger suma_saldo_crap_desde_Eliminar_abonos -- trigger relacionado a cambios_eliminar ejecuta suma de stock
after delete on abonos
for each row
execute procedure suma_saldo_crap_desde_Eliminar_abonos();

create trigger crea_abono_vacio_desde_prestamos -- trigger relacionado a cambios_eliminar ejecuta suma de stock
after insert on prestamos
for each row
execute procedure crea_abono_vacio_desde_prestamos();
```

Y tengo esta consulta para averiguar mi inventario y precio de costo

```
with 
inventario as (
with 
i_ingresos as (select p.codigo_barras, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(sum(i.cantidad),0) as cantidad 
from ingresos_mercancias_detalle i, ingresos_mercancias_cabecera ic, productos p where i.id_ingreso_cabecera=ic.id and i.id_producto=p.id and ic.fecha = '2019-12-31' group by codigo_barras order by codigo_barras),

i_ingresos_ante as (select p.codigo_barras, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(sum(i.cantidad),0) as cantidad 
from ingresos_mercancias_detalle i, ingresos_mercancias_cabecera ic, productos p where i.id_ingreso_cabecera=ic.id and i.id_producto=p.id and ic.fecha < '2019-12-31' group by codigo_barras order by codigo_barras),

i_devoluciones as (select p.codigo_barras, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(sum(dd.cantidad),0) as cantidad 
from productos p, devoluciones dc, devoluciones_detalles dd where dd.id_cabecera_devolucion=dc.id and dd.id_producto=p.id and dc.fecha = '2019-12-31' group by p.codigo_barras),

i_devoluciones_ante as (select p.codigo_barras, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(sum(dd.cantidad),0) as cantidad 
from productos p, devoluciones dc, devoluciones_detalles dd where dd.id_cabecera_devolucion=dc.id and dd.id_producto=p.id and dc.fecha < '2019-12-31' group by p.codigo_barras),

s_ventas as (select p.codigo_barras, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(sum(fd.cantidad),0) as cantidad
from facturas_cabeceras fc, facturas_detalles fd, productos p where fd.id_cabecera=fc.id and fd.id_producto=p.id and fc.estado='1' and fc.fecha = '2019-12-31' group by p.codigo_barras),

s_ventas_ante as (select p.codigo_barras, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(sum(fd.cantidad),0) as cantidad
from facturas_cabeceras fc, facturas_detalles fd, productos p where fd.id_cabecera=fc.id and fd.id_producto=p.id and fc.estado='1' and fc.fecha < '2019-12-31' group by p.codigo_barras),

s_eliminacion as (select p.codigo_barras, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(sum(c.cantidad),0) as cantidad 
from cambios_eliminar c, productos p where c.id_producto=p.id and c.fecha = '2019-12-31' group by p.codigo_barras),

s_eliminacion_ante as (select p.codigo_barras, max(p.descripcion) as descripcion, coalesce(sum(c.cantidad),0) as cantidad 
from cambios_eliminar c, productos p where c.id_producto=p.id and c.fecha < '2019-12-31' group by p.codigo_barras)

select
coalesce(ii.codigo_barras,id.codigo_barras,sv.codigo_barras,se.codigo_barras,iia.codigo_barras,ida.codigo_barras,sva.codigo_barras,sea.codigo_barras) as codigo_barras,
coalesce(ii.descripcion,id.descripcion,sv.descripcion,se.descripcion,iia.descripcion,ida.descripcion,sva.descripcion,sea.descripcion) as descripcion,

sum( coalesce(iia.cantidad,0)+coalesce(ida.cantidad,0)-coalesce(sva.cantidad,0)-coalesce(sea.cantidad,0) +   coalesce(ii.cantidad,0)+coalesce(id.cantidad,0)-coalesce(sv.cantidad,0)-coalesce(se.cantidad,0)      ) as total
from 
i_ingresos as ii
full outer join i_devoluciones as id on ii.codigo_barras=id.codigo_barras
full outer join s_ventas as sv on ii.codigo_barras=sv.codigo_barras
full outer join s_eliminacion se on ii.codigo_barras=se.codigo_barras
full outer join i_ingresos_ante as iia on ii.codigo_barras=iia.codigo_barras
full outer join i_devoluciones_ante as ida on ii.codigo_barras=ida.codigo_barras
full outer join s_ventas_ante as sva on ii.codigo_barras=sva.codigo_barras
full outer join s_eliminacion_ante sea on ii.codigo_barras=sea.codigo_barras

group by coalesce(ii.codigo_barras,id.codigo_barras,sv.codigo_barras,se.codigo_barras,iia.codigo_barras,ida.codigo_barras,sva.codigo_barras,sea.codigo_barras),coalesce(ii.descripcion,id.descripcion,sv.descripcion,se.descripcion,iia.descripcion,ida.descripcion,sva.descripcion,sea.descripcion)
order by coalesce(ii.codigo_barras,id.codigo_barras,sv.codigo_barras,se.codigo_barras,iia.codigo_barras,ida.codigo_barras,sva.codigo_barras,sea.codigo_barras),coalesce(ii.descripcion,id.descripcion,sv.descripcion,se.descripcion,iia.descripcion,ida.descripcion,sva.descripcion,sea.descripcion)),
ultimo_costo as (select p.codigo_barras, 
       i.precio_entrada, 
       maximos.fecha
from ingresos_mercancias_detalle i, 
ingresos_mercancias_cabecera ic, 
productos p, 
(   select p.id, max(ic.fecha) as fecha
    from ingresos_mercancias_detalle i, 
    ingresos_mercancias_cabecera ic, 
    productos p  
    where i.id_ingreso_cabecera=ic.id 
    and i.id_producto=p.id 
    group by p.id
) maximos 
where i.id_ingreso_cabecera=ic.id 
and i.id_producto=p.id 
and i.id_producto = maximos.id 
and ic.fecha = maximos.fecha   
order by i.id_producto)
select i.codigo_barras,i.descripcion,u.precio_entrada as costo,i.total as cantidad, (u.precio_entrada*i.total) as total from inventario i, ultimo_costo u where i.codigo_barras=u.codigo_barras;
```

y me da los siguientes datos como resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que por ejemplo para el producto **CELULAR REDMI 8 64 GB** hice dos ingresos, uno por 440.000 y otro por 200.000 y como resultado me dice que hay 2 a **200.000** yo quisiera que me sumara los precios de costo y promediara el valor real o sea

(1x440000 + 1x200000) / 2 = **320000**

ese es el valor que quiero como resultado en el precio de costo.

como último punto debo tener en cuenta que solamente se deberían promediar los precios de las existencias actuales, ejemplo

tengo 4 ingresos

I1: cantidad 5, costo 100

I2: cantidad 3, costo 70

I3: cantidad 2, costo 180

I4: cantidad 3, costo 200

*I = ingreso*

asumamos que tengo un inventario total de 7 elementos P, entonces mi tabla debería arrojar resultado así

```
codigo_barras | descripcion | cantidad | precio
------------------------------------------------
1             | P           | 7        | 157
```

donde precio lo calcularia de la siguiente manera:

I4 = cantidad 3  x costo 200 = 600

I3 = cantidad 2  x costo 180 = 360

I2 = cantidad **2**  x costo 70 = 140 (solo tomo dos para completar el inventario)

**Total cantidad** *7*  ----- **Total costo** *1100*

precio = 1100/7 = **157.14** = aproximado *157*

Inserts de toda la base de  datos:

[pastebin con los inserts](https://pastebin.com/VQ3KDNKV)

Esa es mi pregunta, sé que es compleja pero necesito de su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Y cómo has intentando resolverlo? ¿Qué error te da? Al modificar la pregunta, no te olvides de aportar los INSERT con los datos de muestra del ejemplo para intentar reproducir tus cálculos

Comment: Me parece que necesitas una tabla de stock aparte para llevar la existencia. En lo que estas mostrando solo están las entradas y minimamente faltan las salidas. De otro modo vas a estar calculando precios promediando items ya vendidos.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es de alto nivel, lo que está complicado es tu regla de negocio, trata de buscar una regla de negocio más sencilla, no sé por qué presiento que estás tratando de almacenar todo en una tabla y pues así no funcionan las cosas.

Comment: Para esta pregunta solamente puse una tabla pero en realidad tengo muchas mas, ventas, devoluciones, etc, voy a colocar toda la base de datos para que tengan el material suficiente

Comment: @Juan ya tengo el inventario con otra consulta, lo que me hace fata es esta parte que publique, que seria como una Subconsulta, por eso no publique todas las tablas

Comment: @DavidJP ya cargue toda la base de datos y los inserts para las pruebas.

Comment: Buenos días @CesarMartinezQuiroga, veo la estructura de las tablas y varias consultas, pero no veo los datos de muestra para las pruebas. En cualquier caso, en la versión anterior de la pregunta habías incluido la etiqueta mysql, en postgresql no tengo instalado el entorno de desarrollo para poder ayudarte, ya lo siento :(

Comment: Trata de focalizar la pregunta a lo que realmente preguntas. Meter toda la base de datos no tiene mucho sentido y hace dificil buscar lo que se necesita. En que tabla llevas el stock? donde esta el stock de cada compra con su precio? Lo que buscas parece que necesita mas un SP que un query. No todo se puede resolver en un query...

Comment: Si te sirve, acabo de responder un problema conceptualmente similar a este quí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/319415/31764, voy a intentar responderte, pero te soy sincero, me apabulla la complejidad de la consulta.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si lo acabo de ver y estoy haciendo las pruebas, todo anda full hasta el momento, la otra pregunta la habia hecho un poco mas sencilla que la de aca pero con eso ya lo puedo usar como subcosulta. muchas gracias

Comment: No había prestado atención que eras el autor de la anterior. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si desea copie aca la respuesta para la recompensa de +50, me funciono perfecto como subconsulta

Answer (score 0):

te dare algunas opciones que yo intentaria :

1- esto realmente no sacaria el promedio si lo deseas como dices aqui es donde se sumaria todo y se dividiria por la cantidad de items.

sum( coalesce(iia.cantidad,0)+coalesce(ida.cantidad,0)

```
-coalesce(sva.cantidad,0)-coalesce(sea.cantidad,0) 
+  coalesce(ii.cantidad,0)+coalesce(id.cantidad,0)
-coalesce(sv.cantidad,0)-coalesce(se.cantidad,0)) as total
```

2- te dejo este link donde puedes revisar un breve ejemplo de un promedio mediante una funcion:
https://living-sun.com/es/sql/811043-sql-weighted-average-sql-postgresql.html

3- y en este ultimo puedes revisar el promedio mediante query (MIRAR LA PARTE FINAL DEL LINK) https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/postgresqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?inicio=25&cod=189&punto=31

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es mas simple de lo que imaginas, tu inventario solo necesitaría salir de tu tabla de productos, veo que le faltaría agregar la cantidad en existencia unitaria de los mismos, esto porque ya tienes tu campo "precio_costo" el cual debería reflejar lo que no puedes obtener con tu larga consulta. Simplemente para resolver tu inconveniente hay que realizar un UPDATE a tu tabla "productos" al momento de hacer tu INSERT a la tabla "ingresos_mercancias_detalle", esto porque el "precio_costo" se debe actualizar con cada nuevo ingreso de mercancía. Así solo necesitas agregar el UPDATE donde "precio_costo" sera igual a (productos.precio_costo * productos.cantidad_en_existencia + NuevoCosto * CantidadAIngresar) / 2 donde el "id_producto" sea igual. Utilizo NuevoCosto y CantidadAIngresar puesto que son los mismos valores que usarías en tu INSERT.

Esto te creara un esquema mas simple y tu tabla Productos es tu inventario real. Ademas, ya que actualizaste en ese mismo o en otro puedes actualizar los nuevos valores de los precios de venta si lo requieres.

Al ver tu estructura de tablas y ver ese campo ("precio_costo") no se en que momento olvidaste su propósito, ya que si deseas ver el primer precio o su histórico de costos para eso esta tus tablas de Ingresos de Mercancías, específicamente "ingresos_mercancias_detalle".

Comment: Un código de ejemplo no estaría mal. Te recomiendo que leas [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Busca sobre funciones de agregación (Suma, Promedio, Contar) y la claúsula GROUP BY para la primera parte de tu problema.

Para el problema del stock, tienes que validar que la columna "Stock" (o como se llame), sea diferente de 0 con un WHERE.

Para la última parte, sobre el promedio, haz un SELECT SUM("Nombre de tu columna cantidad") SUM("Nombre de tu columna precio"). Al select, añadele una nueva columna con la división de ambas y la palabra AS para ponerle un alias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Me temo que esto en mi opinion seria mas un comentario que una respuesta en si. Deberias desarrollar mejor tu respuesta

Comment: @Capt.Teach ah ok, no me percaté del formato

Answer (score 0):

Dado que el costo ponderado depende de dos variables: el id_producto y la cantidad disponible, puedes poner en una función la consulta siguiente (basada en el ejemplo que proporcionaste):

Simplemente reemplaza el id_producto (1) y la cantidad a costear (7) por los valores adecuados.

```
SELECT sum( cantidad_costeable * precio_entrada )/7 costo_ponderado
  FROM ( SELECT * 
              , CASE
                  WHEN acumulado <= 7 THEN cantidad
                  ELSE 7-acumulado+cantidad
                END cantidad_costeable
           FROM ( SELECT fecha, cantidad, precio_entrada
                       , sum( cantidad ) 
                           OVER ( order by fecha desc, hora desc
                                  rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                                ) acumulado
                    FROM ingresos_mercancias_detalle id
                      INNER JOIN ingresos_mercancias_cabecera i
                        ON i.id = id.id_ingreso_cabecera
                    WHERE id_producto = 1
                ) t
       )t
  WHERE cantidad_costeable > 0
```

La consulta consta de tres SELECT anidados:

- **El más profundo** con ayuda de *window functions* obtiene el acumulado de ingresos desde la entrada más reciente.
- El **intermedio** es únicamente para determinar la cantidad a costear basado en las existencias actuales.
- El **principal** es únicamente para descartar los registros no costeables y calcular el costo promedio.