# Calcular promedio ponderado de costo de productos con cantidad previa

Tags: postgresql, sql

tengo la siguiente tabla de ingresos de mercancía

```
CREATE TABLE ingresos_mercancias_detalle
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_producto integer,
  cantidad double precision,
  precio_entrada double precision,
  fecha date,
  CONSTRAINT pk_ingresos_detalle PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

ella va a tener una x cantidad de ingresos de cada producto donde registramos la fecha, cantidad y costo

lo que quiero es averiguar el promedio ponderado basándonos en una cantidad dada, por ejemplo:

tengo estos datos en mi tabla

```
insert into ingresos_mercancias_detalle values(1,1,5,100,'2019-12-01');
insert into ingresos_mercancias_detalle values(2,1,8,120,'2019-12-05');
insert into ingresos_mercancias_detalle values(3,1,10,80,'2019-12-07');
insert into ingresos_mercancias_detalle values(4,1,2,300,'2019-12-20');
insert into ingresos_mercancias_detalle values(5,1,4,200,'2019-12-30');
```

y tengo esta consulta

```
select id_producto, sum(cantidad) as cantidad, sum(precio_entrada*cantidad) as total_entrada, (sum(precio_entrada*cantidad)/sum(cantidad)) as promedio_ponderado from ingresos_mercancias_detalle group by id_producto
```

que me retorna los siguientes datos:

[image: consulta promedio ponderado]

hasta ahí todo es fácil, mi problema es cuando yo quiero saber el promedio ponderador de los **ultimos** X cantidad de productos.

**Ejemplo:**
quiero averiguar el promedio ponderado de los últimos **19** productos

para ello deberia tomar los registros ordenados por fecha de la más nueva a la más antigua y sumar las cantidades (selección verde)

```
select * from ingresos_mercancias_detalle order by fecha desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces tomaría

- **4** de el registro con fecha 2019-12-30
- **2** de el registro con fecha 2019-12-20
- **10** de el registro con fecha 2019-12-07
- **3** de el registro con fecha 2019-12-05 (solamente 3 de los 8 para completar 19)

para un total de 19 esto me daría como promedio ponderado

((4*200)+(2*300)+(10*80)+( **3** *120)) / 19 = **124.210**

¿Como hago para que la consulta use la cantidad que yo le de (la enviará desde el software) y me retorna el promedio ponderado de la cantidad dada?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a plantear una alternativa con `sql` bien básico, lo primero es saber que cantidad vamos a tomar de cada fila en función del número de ventas y con esa cantidad obtener el precio_ponderado de cada fila:

```
select  md1.id_producto, 
    md1.cantidad,
    md1.precio_entrada,
    md1.fecha,
    case    when 19 - COALESCE(sum(md2.cantidad),0) >= md1.cantidad then  md1.cantidad
            when 19 - COALESCE(sum(md2.cantidad),0) < 0 then 0
            else 19 - COALESCE(sum(md2.cantidad),0)
    end * md1.precio_entrada as precio_ponderado
    from ingresos_mercancias_detalle md1
    left join ingresos_mercancias_detalle md2
        on md1.id_producto = md2.id_producto
        and md1.fecha < md2.fecha
    group by 
        md1.id_producto, 
        md1.cantidad,
        md1.precio_entrada,
        md1.fecha
    order by md1.fecha desc;
```

Resultado:

```
| id_producto | cantidad | precio_entrada |      fecha | precio_ponderado |
|-------------|----------|----------------|------------|------------------|
|           1 |        4 |            200 | 2019-12-30 |              800 |
|           1 |        2 |            300 | 2019-12-20 |              600 |
|           1 |       10 |             80 | 2019-12-07 |              800 |
|           1 |        8 |            120 | 2019-12-05 |              360 |
|           1 |        5 |            100 | 2019-12-01 |                0 |
```

La consulta es una recursión sobre la misma tabla, para calcular la suma acumulada y un poco de lógica en un `case` pasa saber cuando hemos alcanzado el límite de cantidad. Con esta consulta, en `postgresql` (al menos) funcionaría usarla de subconsulta para obtener el total final ponderado por producto:

```
select t.id_producto,
       sum(t.precio_ponderado)/19.0 as precio_final_ponderado
       from (select md1.id_producto, 
                    md1.cantidad,
                    md1.precio_entrada,
                    md1.fecha,
                    case    when 19 - COALESCE(sum(md2.cantidad),0) >= md1.cantidad then  md1.cantidad
                            when 19 - COALESCE(sum(md2.cantidad),0) < 0 then 0
                            else 19 - COALESCE(sum(md2.cantidad),0)
                    end * md1.precio_entrada as precio_ponderado
                    from ingresos_mercancias_detalle md1
                    left join ingresos_mercancias_detalle md2
                        on md1.id_producto = md2.id_producto
                        and md1.fecha < md2.fecha
                    group by 
                        md1.id_producto, 
                        md1.cantidad,
                        md1.precio_entrada,
                        md1.fecha
                    order by md1.fecha desc
             ) t
       group by t.id_producto;
```

Resultado:

```
| id_producto | precio_final_ponderado |
|-------------|------------------------|
|           1 |     134.73684210526315 |
```

Comentarios:

- En tu pregunta tienes un error, el total no es `((4*200)+(2*200)+(10*80)+(3*120))` sino `((4*200)+(2*300)+(10*80)+(3*120))`
- [Aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6306d/14/0) un fiddle